# Android emulator does not take enter button of my PCs Keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have enabled my 'hardware keyboard'(my PCs keyboard) in android emulator. For an `EditText` I have set `ImeAction` as `IME_ACTION_DONE`.

This setup works fine when I use virtual keyboard on my emulator or keybaords of any android devices. But not when I press enter button on my PCs keybaord when I have enabled 'hardware keyboard' present.

Do we need to press some key other than 'enter' key to perform IME_ACTION_DONE on emulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Enter</kbd> in pc keyboard doesn't represent the key `Done` in android soft keyboard, also it has a separate `KeyEvent` to handle with, So to deal with it like `Done`, you have to handle it's event in combination with the event of `Done` button:

```
    mView.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                    || (event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))) {
                //TODO do whatever you want
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

have a look at <kbd>Enter</kbd> KeyEvent [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_ENTER).

**UPDATE:**

as per [Android Emulator Keyboard Mapping](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) there **isn't** a key that represents `Done` key which is in android soft keyboard:

[image]

Comment: I understood that enter key of PC doesn't perform IME_ACTION_DONE. So which PC keyboard key could do this job?

Answer (score 0):

The hardware keyboard option tells the emulator that an external (not virtual) keyboard is connected to android.

Therefor you might need to look into [KeyEvents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html).

However usually the emulator works out of the box with the IME_ACTION_DONE.

ps: Also take a look into [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) as an emulator! As it is way faster than the default emulator.